# is there a quick way to retrieve the entire (100% of fields) profile from an organization?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

is there a quick way to retrieve the entire (100% of fields) profile from an organization? I need retrieve all profiles data from org. How can i do this ? If i try add all metadata types to package.xml the process is not completed due to the large amount of data.

Comment: What's the exact message you get when you attempt to retrieve using all the metadata types within the package.xml? What have you actually tried (sfdx command)?

Comment: @kris it just freezes, left for a couple of hours 0 changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background

When retrieving Metadata most tools use the [retrieve()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) call from the File-based Metadata API. This only returns permissions of the Metadata Components that are specified in the given manifest.

Example:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile:Admin,CustomField:Account.VAT__c
```

### Solution

A full `Profile` is returned if you use the [readMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm) call from the CRUD (REST) Metadata API.

As this call returns JSON, you might need to convert it to XML.

One sfdx plugin which does that is [sfdx-plugin-source-read](https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-plugin-source-read).

Example: (hint: `read` instead of `retrieve`)

```
sfdx plugins:install sfdx-plugin-source-read
sfdx force:source:read -m Profile:Admin
```