# How to retrieve profile's all metadata in vscode?

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, vs-code

I want to retrieve profile's all metadata which include fields permission, classes permission , layout assignment. I tried few ways which didn't seems to work

1. Using package.xml : I have added profile, classes and layout for which I want access metadata for that profile
2. sfdx command : I have used `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Profile:Admin"` to retrive Admin profile's metadata but it didn't retrieve all the information about the profile

Is there a way to retrieve profile's complete information?

Comment: Does the answer on this question help you? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357223/is-there-a-quick-way-to-retrieve-the-entire-100-of-fields-profile-from-an-org

Comment: Hi @dschib,
It solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a quick way to retrieve the entire (100% of fields) profile from an organization?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357223/is-there-a-quick-way-to-retrieve-the-entire-100-of-fields-profile-from-an-org)